# Form only edited on refresh - Django

Tags: python, django

The user enters data and receives the following error: "'function' object has no attribute 'id.'" Yet, when they refresh the page, the page that the form modifies *has* been successfully updated. Here is the section of views.py that the error is attached to. The line in question is `return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)`

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
"""Edit an existing entry."""
entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)

if request.method != 'POST':
    # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry.
    form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
else:
    #POST data submitted; process data.
    form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)

context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

`topic` is a function in views.py--see below (there is also a class in models.py called `Topic`.

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Here is the error:

```
Django version 2.2.12, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /edit_entry/6/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\14254\Desktop\Programming\Projects\(Mathes) Learning Log\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\14254\Desktop\Programming\Projects\(Mathes) Learning Log\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\14254\Desktop\Programming\Projects\(Mathes) Learning Log\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\14254\Desktop\Programming\Projects\(Mathes) Learning Log\learning_log\learning_logs\views.py", line 74, in edit_entry
    return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'
[16/May/2020 18:29:37] "POST /edit_entry/6/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68121
```

Comment: Can you provide what is the topic value before redirect call? I guess you override topic instance with a function.

Comment: @DenizKaplan: `topic` is likely just another view function.

Comment: @DenizKaplan @WillemVanOnsem Edited original post to show `topic`.

Answer (score 0):

`topic` is likely another view function in your `views.py`. This thus means that `topic.id` will try to obtain the `.id` attribute of that view, but a function normally has no `.id` attribute.

What you can do is object the result of `form.save()` and store that in a *local* variable named `topic`:

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Edit an existing entry."""
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        #POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=entry.id)
    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': entry, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

Comment: This solution now returns the error "local variable 'topic' referenced before assignment" at the second to last line.

Comment: @Researcher2020: yes, because earlier, you passed the `topic` view function to the template. What is the difference between `topic` en `Entry`?

Answer (score 0):

As `topic` is a view function, you need to change

```py
return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic.id)
```

to

```py
return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=entry.topic_id)
```

As @Willem Van Onsem mentioned, a view function has no attribute id attribute to access.